# Using expressions inside an ng-option tag in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to create a custom directive like this:

**app.js**

```
sampleApp
.directive("selectDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl : "directive.html",
        scope: {
            spListField: "=spField",        
            firstOptText: "@",
            selectWidthPx: "@",
            ngModel: "="
        }
    };
});
```

I initialize the spListField property of my directive to this:

```
{fieldOptions: results.value, textColumn: 'RoomName', valueColumn: 'RoomNumber'};
```

where results.value is obtained as a result of angular $http call.

**directive.html**

```
<select     
    ng-model="ngModel" 
    ng-options="fieldOption['{{spListField.valueColumn}}'] 
                as fieldOption['{{spListField.textColumn}}'] 
                for fieldOption 
                in spListField.fieldOptions | unique: '{{spListField.textColumn}}' | orderBy: '{{spListField.textColumn}}' : false  
                track by fieldOption['{{spListField.valueColumn}}']">
    <option value="">{{firstOptText}}</option>
```

The problem is although my model value is coming up correctly from the service, my view (the select rendered by the directive) doesn't update. I get "undefined" as options in my select element. 
Strangely if I hard code the ng-options attributes like shown below, it works.

```
<select class="FilterDDL"
    ng-style="{width: selectWidthPx + 'px'}" 
    ng-model="ngModel" 
    ng-options="fieldOption['RoomNumber'] 
                as fieldOption['RoomName'] 
                for fieldOption 
                in spListField.fieldOptions | unique: '{{spListField.textColumn}}' | orderBy: '{{spListField.textColumn}}' : false  
                track by fieldOption['{{spListField.valueColumn}}']">
    <option value="">{{firstOptText}}</option>
```

But I can't reuse my directive this way. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried jquery $.ajax instead of $http in my service code to obtain the results.value object and it works with my original directive HTML. Now I am completely confused.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce in a Plunkr? This seems like you are referencing textColumn and valueColumn incorrectly in your view. Have you tried it without the brackets or single quotes?

Comment: I haven't tried put it in plunkr yet as that would take some time. This is part of a much bigger file. But will do that soon.
However I have tried without brackets and quotes and it doesn't work.